# How to loop through array of object literals?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, interpolation, object-literal

I have Angular project with drag and drop module. Now my draggable list is contained inside array of objects, like so:

```js
vegetables = [
    {name: 'Carrot', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Onion', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Capsicum', type: 'vegetable'}];
```

and I'm showing it in my component, like so:

```html
<div class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-success" [draggable] 
       *ngFor="let item of vegetables" [dragClass]="'active'" [dragTransitClass]="'active'" 
       [dragData]="item" [dragScope]="item.type" [dragEnabled]="dragEnabled">
                            {{item.name}}
   </li>
</div>
```

The thing is that every time I drag and drop one of the items from `vegetables` list, I want to show a new list with new vegetables.

So I tried doing something like this:

```js
vegetables = [
    {name: 'Carrot', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Onion', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Potato', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Capsicum', type: 'vegetable'}],
    [
    {name: 'Carrot2', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Onion2', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Potato2', type: 'vegetable'},
    {name: 'Capsicum2', type: 'vegetable'}
    ];
```

which is having multiple arrays of objects inside `vegetables` variable.

But the thing is that I don't know how to display it inside my component template. I tried this:

```html
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-success"
    [draggable] *ngFor="let item of vegetables[i]" ...>
```

where `i` would be just incremental variable every time I drag and drop one time from `vegetables` list gets incremented, but of course it doesn't work like that and I don't know the right way to do this.

So how can I iterate through multiple arrays inside `vegetables` to render a new list of veggies every time I drag and drop?

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That syntax for `vegetables` there isn't valid: you need to wrap it in another set of `[ ]`. Once you've done that, you would need multiple `ngFor` loops

Comment: Do you have any example, because I don't know how to stack multiple ngFor's to the same property `draggable`. I'm pretty new to angular